# Is there a way to include the same Mixin more than once in a subclass in Python?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mixins

Normally a Python mixin would only be included once, like:

```
class MyMixin:
    pass
class Child(Base, MyMixin):
    pass
```

However, in some situation it would be handy if we can use the same Mixin twice. 
For example, I have a Mixin in SQLAlchemy defining some Columns as follow:

```
class MyNoteMixin:
    note = Column(String)
    by_who = Column(String)
```

Now I have a subclass that inherits from the above Mixin, but needs two different columns both are of a note nature. Can I do something like:

```
class Child(Base, MyNoteMixin as "Description", MyNoteMixin as "Quote"):
        pass
```

So that the resolved table would contain a column named Description that is exactly a MyNoteMixin copy except for the name, AND also has another column named Quote with the same nature.

Is this possible with SQLAlchemy? Or generally speaking, is such usage of Mixin even possible in Python? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [python decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-decorator).

Here is an example how to get this using plan python class:

```
def custom_fields(**kwargs):
    def wrap(original_class):
        """
        Apply here your logic, could be anything!
        """
        for key, val in kwargs.items():
            setattr(original_class, key, val)
        return original_class
    return wrap


@custom_fields(quote='String here, can be SQLAlchemy column object')
class Child:
    pass


print(Child.quote)
```

Output:

```
>>> String here, can be SQLAlchemy column object
```

You will have to adapt it for sqlalchemy, like connect the `setattr` to your `MyNoteMixin`.

Comment: Thanks Or, excellent point for giving the direction of decorator. I will just give this post a little more time to see if others have some ideas to share. This one is so far the *best*!

Comment: Just upvoted:) I will definitely mark this one as the chosen answer given a little more time no other feedback. Just want to invite a little more thinking.

Comment: @ Or Duan, could you think of any potential problems using this method? I'm just curious why the SQLAlchemy official documentation recommends Mixin rather than decorator pattern, to tackle to problem of boilerplates. But I'm convinced that the decorator pattern is just as good. Is there any reason people not using this?

Comment: @JinghuiNiu using mixin has it own pros, like inheritance, overrides and other OO benefits, your case is impossible to implement with mixins since you need to change the class before it was called/initialized it's not possible in python unless you wrap it with another factory class - tons of code and much more complexity. The big disadvantage here is readability, just think of a new developer that have no idea why and how this works and why the class works different then the code looks.